# How to get the selected item ids from multi selectable combo box in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I want to get the selected item ids in a String array (preferably). How to get the selected item ids when multiple items are selected?

Comment: The getValue(...) returns a array of selected values

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-selection.html#components.selection.getset) is often helpful :-)

> You can select an item with the corresponding setValue() method. In multiselect mode, the property will be an unmodifiable **set of item identifiers**. If no item is selected, the property will be null in single selection mode or an empty collection in multiselect mode.

So after casting `comboBox.getValue()` to `Set<?>` you can call `toArray(new String[0])` to get the desired array.